# How to patch `\LoadClass` in a LaTeX class to change the parent class without modifying the .cls file?

Tags: etoolbox, dtx, l3doc

I am currently experimenting with .dtx files to develop a little style for my university documents. Doing so, I use `l3doc` class as a document class in the documentation counterpart of my dtx file.
However, I am using KOMA-Script in the same time, using command from my generated sty file and as class for future documents, and I wanted to use the sty file generated for the dtx documentation itself.

As `l3doc` is based on the `article` class, the KOMA-Script specific commands are not available by default. What I did for the moment is to get the [l3doc dtx file](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/), and change the `\LoadCLass` parameter to use `scrartcl` instead.

Is there a way to patch the class without changing the cls file itself ?

I tried using `etoolbox` and `\patchcmd`, but I did not achieve to do so.

```tex
\makeatletter
  \patchcmd{\LoadClass}
  {article}
  {scrreprt}
  {} ^^A Success code (empty for this example)
  {\@latex@error{Patching \string\LoadClass\space failed}}
\makeatother
```

ref. https://framagit.org/sortion/mus (see [this commit](https://framagit.org/sortion/mus/-/commit/05b923f0182ea4304526270d24bd30758dd22585) more specifically, for instance)

ps. I also tried using `\usepackage{scrextend}` but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patching `\LoadClass` this way cannot work, because there is no `article` in the definition of `\LoadClass` (only in the usage of `\LoadClass` inside `l3doc.cls`). It would work to redefine `\LoadClass` using a test for the class name argument and replace it, if this is `scrartcl`. But there is an easier way:

IHMO exactly what you want is done by `koma-script-source-doc.cls` for loading `scrartcl` instead of `article` when using `ltxdoc`:

```latex
\IfFileExists{scrartcl.cls}{%
  \declare@file@substitution{article.cls}{scrartcl.cls}
  \PassOptionsToClass{fontsize=10pt}{scrartcl}
}{%
  \ClassWarningNoLine{koma-script-source-doc}{%
    Usually this class should be used with KOMA-Script\MessageBreak
    scrartcl. But as that class is not available we use\MessageBreak
    standard class article as emergency fallback.\MessageBreak
    It is recommended to repeat this LaTeX run after\MessageBreak
    build/installation of a complete KOMA-Script%
  }%
}
\LoadClassWithOptions{ltxdoc}[2021/12/07]
```

The important code line is:

```latex
\declare@file@substitution{article.cls}{scrartcl.cls}
```

`\declare@file@substitution` is documented in [`ltfilehook-doc.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltfilehook-doc.pdf).

Another suggestion would be to load `scrlfile`. It provides a command `\ReplaceClass`. This would also work with older versions of LaTeX.

Just a note: I don't know why using `\usepackage{scrextend}` was without success in you case. I've tested to load `scrextend` after `l3doc`:

```latex
\documentclass{l3doc}

\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}
\dictum{Works}
\end{document}
```

and this was successful. But maybe you meant, that `scrextend` does not provide one of the commands, you want to use. So please be more concrete next time.